# How to write JUnit testcases for non-public fragments or methods in Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-fragments, junit

Is there anyway to write Junit testcases for my non-public fields, methods and fragments in Android.

Please suggest any way to proceed with writing testcases for private and default members in android

Comment: Does the behavior you're testing really need to be part of the fragment? Can the fragment depend on separate classes that encapsulate that logic that can be more easily tested?

Answer (score 0):

Anything that needs to be unit tested is likely somewhat independent from the android lifecycle. In that case, try to refactor those things into different methods or classes so that you can then write unit tests just for the helpers.

Answer (score 0):

Use some library, which allows to test private methods using Reflection. But in most cases, if you need to test private methods to ensure good testing, means design has flaws and you should consider refactoring the code. If it's not possible for some reason - look at PowerMock.